# Animated game for web and iPhone - how?

Tags: iphone

I would like to create arcade game (cartoon style). I need framework/technology to create one code and use it on website and iPhone in same way. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

- [Unity 3D](http://unity3d.com/) (needs a plugin on the web)
- [HTML5 + Canvas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element) (via mobile Safari on the iPhone)

Answer (score 0):

The very popular cocos2d framework is now available in a JavaScript/HTML flavor. The press release has more specific information:

[The first joint release of the cocos2d family](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/news/81)

cocos2d is free and heavily used. There are numerous tutorials on the iPhone variant that are somewhat adaptable to the -x variant. One, very popular iOS tutorial site [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/), has lots of great information to get started.

There is active discussion and work being done with cocos2d to make one codebase work across iOS, Android, Windows Phone, Blackberry, and HTML.